# Creating a subpage through Notion API

Tags: notion-api

I am trying to create a subpage in a page using Notion-api
In the [update block documentation][1] it asks us to use update page end point.
But it is not clear how to use it to add a sub-page within a page.
Any help will be great.
Thanks!
[1]: https://developers.notion.com/reference/update-a-block